# How to do multiple aggregations in a "has through" relationship in a single query using Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, eloquent

I have the following tables:

### Venues

- id

### Offers

- id
- venue_id

### Orders

- id
- offer_id
- quantity

Venues can have many offers, and offers can have many orders. This is all modelled in the appropriate Eloquent models like so:

```
class Venue extends Model
{
    public function offers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Offer::class);
    }
}

class Offer extends Model
{
    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
    }
}
```

I want to run a single query which allows me to see every venue and the number of orders it has. e.g.

```
venue_id | number_of_orders
---------------------------
5        | 20
15       | 0
8        | 123
```

I was easily able to do this using raw SQL like so:

```
select venues.id, sum(offersGrouped.number_of_orders) as total_number_of_orders
from venues
left outer join (
   select offers.id, offers.venue_id, sum(orders.quantity) as number_of_orders
   from offers
   left outer join orders on offers.id = orders.offer_id
   group by offers.id
) offersGrouped on venues.id = offersGrouped.venue_id
group by venues.id;
```

However, how can I do the same thing using Eloquent?

I am using Laravel 5.1, but I don't mind if answers uses features from newer versions of Laravel if required.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `HasManyThrough` relationship to your `Venue` model:

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Order::class, Offer::class);
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
$venues = Venue::with('orders')->get();
foreach($venues as $venue) {
    // $venue->orders->sum('quantity')
}
```

Or an in-database solution:

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Order::class, Offer::class)
        ->groupBy('venue_id')->selectRaw('SUM(quantity) sum');
}

$venues = Venue::with('orders')->get();
foreach($venues as $venue) {
    if($venue->orders->isNotEmpty()) {
        // $venue->orders->first()->sum
    } else {
        // 0
    }
}
```

Comment: But I want to sum the quantity

Comment: This is not very efficient as you have to fetch all orders and then perform the loop. The SQL in the question returns the total directly.